# Read contents of file with appropriate error handling (Rust)

Tags: error-handling, file-system, rust

I am trying to learn basic Rust. Is this a good way to get the contents of a file? Am I handling errors the best way? Is there any way this could be more performant?

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::Read;

fn main() {
    let path = "bar/foo.txt";

    match read(path) {
        Ok(contents) => println!("{}", contents),
        Err(err) => println!("Unable to read '{}': {}", path, err),
    }
}

fn read(file: &str) -> Result<String, std::io::Error> {
    let mut file = match File::open(file) {
        Ok(mut f) => f,
        Err(err) => return Err(err),
    };

    let mut data = String::new();
    match file.read_to_string(&mut data) {
        Ok(_) => return Ok(data),
        Err(err) => return Err(err),
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Your code gives a warning:

   ```
   warning: variable does not need to be mutable
     --> src/main.rs:15:12
      |
   15 |         Ok(mut f) => f,
      |            ^^^^^
      |
   ```

   When you move a value from one binding to another, the two bindings don't have to agree on mutability. It may sound strange, but it's valid to move from an immutable binding to a mutable binding. It's perfectly safe because in order to be able to move a value, there must not be any pointers to it, which ensures that you have exclusive access to the value. Therefore, you could write `Ok(f)` here instead of `Ok(mut f)`.
2. The `match / return Err` pattern is so frequent that Rust has a shorthand for it: [the `?` operator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html#a-shortcut-for-propagating-errors-) (and its predecessor, the [`try!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/macro.try.html) macro). We could rewrite your program using the `?` operator like this:

   ```
   use std::fs::File;
   use std::io::Read;

   fn main() {
       let path = "bar/foo.txt";

       match read(path) {
           Ok(contents) => println!("{}", contents),
           Err(err) => println!("Unable to read '{}': {}", path, err),
       }
   }

   fn read(file: &str) -> Result<String, std::io::Error> {
       let mut file = File::open(file)?;

       let mut data = String::new();
       file.read_to_string(&mut data)?;
       Ok(data)
   }
   ```

   The second `match` in `read` ends the function, so we don't need the `?` operator. Instead, we could use [`map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.map) to replace the data in the `Ok` variant while keeping the `Err` the same, and then just return the result of `map`.

   ```
   fn read(file: &str) -> Result<String, std::io::Error> {
       let mut file = File::open(file)?;

       let mut data = String::new();
       file.read_to_string(&mut data).map(|_| data)
   }
   ```

   Which one you use is up to you. :)
3. [`File::open`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fs/struct.File.html#method.open) accepts more than just `&str`. Its signature is:

   ```
   fn open<P: AsRef<Path>>(path: P) -> Result<File>
   ```

   You could make your own `read` function more generic by introducing a type parameter.

   ```
   use std::path::Path;

   fn read<P: AsRef<Path>>(file: P) -> Result<String, std::io::Error> {
       let mut file = File::open(file)?;

       let mut data = String::new();
       file.read_to_string(&mut data)?;
       Ok(data)
   }
   ```

   Look at the list of [implementations for `AsRef<Path>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/convert/trait.AsRef.html#implementors) to see what types you can now pass to your function.

Comment: The reason for this apparently overcomplicated string handling is that filenames aren't required to be valid unicode while `String`/`&str` require valid unicode.